# Chrome repeat large headers when printing to pdf

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pdf

I need to make a repeating header with chrome when printing to pdf. Using a thead works. But not when the thead gets too large. If I make #header smaller then 74mm then it works. But that's not enough for my use case.

The snippet has a few rows with a margin bottom to generate the multiple pages.

```js
window.print();
```

```css
@page {
  size: A4;
  margin:0;
}



@media print{
  div{
    margin-bottom: 50mm;
  }
  table{
    width:100%;
  }
  #header {
    height: 80mm;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div id="header">I'm the header</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>Row</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>Row</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>Row</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>Row</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```